# Conditional Formatting with partial match

Tags: string, excel, search, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx4AlUFuxYrQaHZYUklFSENLRlk/view?usp=sharing

I have a spreadsheet that uses an INDEX and AGGREGATE formula to populate results from a searched line item. I would like to add Conditional Formatting to the results to make it easier to find.

For example, if I type `tax` instead of `taxiing,` results that have a partial match will populate as module numbers, Lesson 1, Lesson 2, etc. Now I would like the items in Column B to be highlighted that partially match `tax.`

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

With `tax` in, say, D1 please select ColumnB and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=SEARCH(D$1,B1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, OK, OK.

[SEARCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/search.php) looks for the string in D1 within the string in B1. If found it returns a number, if not an error (which CF will ignore). It is not case sensitive. CF considers a numeric result to be a 'hit' to trigger the chosen formatting. By selecting the entire column the Applies to range is set from B1 (where the above formula is first applied) down to the end of the column, with CF automatically stepping through the `B` cells (because the row number is not anchored) but not `D1` because that reference is anchored (with the `$`).